# Confusion between an ordered pair, and open interval

Tags: terminology, analytic-geometry

> > The **$(x, y)$ plane** is the set of all ordered pairs $(x, y)$ of real numbers. The origin is the point $(0, 0)$. The $x$-axis is the set of all points of the form $(x, 0)$, and the $y$-axis is the set of all points of the form $(0, y)$.

I am confused that whether in this definition the term "$(x, y)$ plane" represents an ordered pair, open interval or it is used to just represent that the plane belongs to $x$-axis and $y$-axis.

Answer (score 3):

It refers to the plane, ie, all points of the form $(x,y)$. The notation is the same for an open interval, unfortunately, albeit the context usually serves to disambiguate. Some people use $]a,b[$ to denote an open interval, but that never really caught on. Changing entrenched notation is close to impossible...

Comment: Some people use $\langle x, y\rangle$ to denote ordered tuples, but I've never seen it used consistently outside logic and related (over-formalized?) fields.

Comment: @copper.hat You mean it refers to the plane in which all the points are of the form (x, y)?

Comment: It refers to a two dimensional real plane.

Comment: All the points will correspond to the respective ordered pair of the form (x, y) in the (x, y)plane. Here (x, y)plane refers to x and y coordinate which automatically means a two dimensional real plane?

Comment: Yes. Also known as $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Comment: Well, we could refer to a two dimensional plane as 'x and y plane', can't we?

Comment: Sure. I think of a plane, rather than the specific coordinate system. I think people say $x-y$ plane because they learn about $x,y$-coordinates in school, and when the terms $x,y$ appear, they implicitly refer to this coordinate system. Much is personal preference and what works for you.

Comment: Very conclusively, the term $(x, y)plane$ refers to a two-dimensional plane in which every point will have an $x$ and a $y$ coordinate. If a point $P$ lets say, lies on the $(x, y)plane$ then it can be written as $P(x_0, y_0)$, and the point $P$ has two coordinates $x_0$ and $y_0$? That's why $(x, y)$ in $(x, y) plane$ refers to a specific system of coordinates in which the ordered pairs are of the form $(x, y)$?